# Knex.js: LATERAL Joins

Tags: postgresql, join, knex.js

Is there any way to use lateral joins with knex.js?  It seems to be the only solution to my specific issue, but knex.js lacks a `.lateral` or a way to set it via raw.

Comment: You can do something like this `knex.select('m.name').from('manufactures as m').joinRaw('LEFT JOIN LATERAL get_product_names(m.id) pname on true').whereRaw('pname IS NULL')`

Comment: If you can, share the table details, so I think that I can be more assertive.

Answer (score 4):

The only way would be through using [.joinRaw](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-joinRaw).

Also, there is an open issue on GitHub regarding this topic https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3732